# Infinitely many squares of the from $1 + 2^{x^2} + 2^{y^2}$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that there exist infinitely many squares of the form

$$1 + 2^{x^2} + 2^{y^2}$$

where $x$ and $y $ positive integers.

Also, is there a general form for the solutions so that one can generate solutions from it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need $a$ such that  $a^2 = 2^{x^2}$ and $2a = 2^{y^2}$, so then we can get

$$ 1 + 2^{x^2} + 2^{y^2} = (a + 1)^2$$

This would imply that $x = 2k$ fro some natural number $k$, which would give us $a = 2^{2k^2} = 2^{y^2−1}$, which gives us the following pell equation :)

$$y^2 - 2k^2 = 1 $$

which has infinitely many solutions of the form 
$y_n +k_n \sqrt{2} = (3 + 2 \sqrt{2})^n $

Comment: I would say is *suffices* to find (infinitely many) $a$ such that $a^2=2^{x^2}$ and $2a=2^{y^2}$.  I.e., this (very nice!) answer produces infinitely many solutions, but it may or may not account for *all* solutions.

Comment: Yup. The above might be (mostly) only one of the families of solutions